# Get substring within a string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, substring

I come to find some guidance on accomplishing the following:

I have a variable with content like this:

```
varname = asdfiuytgy12$gggsy22.oihbcxew
```

or

```
varname = oiujedc$thisisit.oiju
```

which `$` and `.` are exactly my partters and I need to get what is within them so `gggsy22` or `thisisit`.

I need to use batch to create a simple bat file. I hope someone can provide some guidance.

**Edit** - *(from comment section)*

Actually a friend of mine helped and it did work but with a quite amount of lines:

```
Set "sstr=$"
SET stemp=%nameVar%&SET pos=0

:loop
SET /a pos+=1
echo %stemp%|FINDSTR /b /c:"%sstr%" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    SET stemp=%stemp:~1%
    IF DEFINED stemp GOTO loop
    SET pos=0
)
Set "pos1=%pos%"
Set "sstr=."
SET stemp=%nameVar%&SET pos=0

:loop
SET /a pos+=1
echo %stemp%|FINDSTR /b /c:"%sstr%" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    SET stemp=%stemp:~1%
    IF DEFINED stemp GOTO loop
    SET pos=0
)
Set "pos2=%pos%"
set /a "pos2=%pos2%-%pos1%-1"
call set env=%%nameVar:~%pos1%,%pos2%%%
```

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Type `set /?` and `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help texts very carefully; I'm sure you'll find something helpful...

Comment: Actually a friend of mine helped and it did work but with a quite amount of lines:

Comment: Set "sstr=$"
SET stemp=%nameVar%&SET pos=0

:loop
SET /a pos+=1
echo %stemp%|FINDSTR /b /c:"%sstr%" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
SET stemp=%stemp:~1%
IF DEFINED stemp GOTO loop
SET pos=0
)

Set "pos1=%pos%"

Set "sstr=."
SET stemp=%nameVar%&SET pos=0

:loop
SET /a pos+=1
echo %stemp%|FINDSTR /b /c:"%sstr%" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
SET stemp=%stemp:~1%
IF DEFINED stemp GOTO loop
SET pos=0
)

Set "pos2=%pos%"

set /a "pos2=%pos2%-%pos1%-1"

call set env=%%nameVar:~%pos1%,%pos2%%%

Comment: Please include the code in your question as it is not readable in a comment...

Comment: That code in your Edit cannot possibly work. The logic is wrong, and your use of duplicate :label names will result in unwanted loop cross pollination.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
set "varname=asdfiuytgy12$gggsy22.oihbcxew"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=$." %%a in ("%varname%") do set "sub=%%a"
```

Comment: This would give an erroneous result with a string like `abc$123$xyz` or `abc.123.xyz` or `abc$123` or `abc.123`.

Comment: This would also fail with a string like `abc$.xyz`

Answer (score 1):

The following works in nearly any situation. The only thing that could break the code is if the string contains a quote `"` followed by a poison character like `&`, `|`, etc.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "str=oiujedc$thisisit.oiju"

:: Verify string exists and has the proper format
echo "%str%"|findstr "\$.*\." >nul || (echo Value not found & exit /b)

:: Extract the value
:: The extra "x" is needed in case there is no character between $ and .,
:: in which case the result should be No Value (result variable not defined)
for /f "delims=." %%A in ("x%str:*$=%") do set "val=%%A"
set "val=%val:~1%"

:: Show the result
echo value = "%val%"
```

A bullet proof variant can be made by incorporating delayed expansion.

Comment: Wouldn't the first check be more exact/easier with `findstr "\$..*\." >nul` or `findstr "\$[^$.][^$.]*\." >nul `?

Comment: Your comment seems off track as this is about strings with `$` and `.` not files with an underscore. Your above code will return wrong results with (of course construed) strings like `"oiujedc$a$thisisit.oiju" , "oiujedc$.a$thisisit..oiju" or "oiujedc$$thisisit..oiju"`

Comment: @LotPings - Sorry, my head was in the wrong (totally unrelated) Q&A when I wrote my (deleted) comment. I'm back on topic :-) I am assuming that an empty string from `xxx$.xxxx` is a valid result, but a source string without `$` and or `.` is invalid,  which is why I did not use your first regex. I wanted to be able to differentiate between the two scenarios. If no need to differentiate, then i like your first regex. As to whether my results are wrong with your construed strings, that is debatable. The OP did not specify how to handle multiple `$` and/or `.`.

Comment: @LotPings - My code consistently handles multiple `$` or `.` in a reliable way. I begin extracting immediately after the first occurrence of `$`, and stop at the next occurrence of `.`. My code allows `$` to be in the resultant value.